# How can I make the test jar include dependencies in Maven?

Tags: maven, jar, dependency-management

I have a project with src/main/java and src/test/java structure, and I managed to use maven-jar-plugin to build a jar of the test branch. However, I want to package the test jar so that all the dependencies are resolved. Is there a way I can tell maven-jar-plugin to include the dependencies??

Thanks!

Frank

Comment: Your question is unclear. Do you want to include all test dependencies with the test jar or do you want then to be correctly resolved as test deps?

Comment: I want to add the dependencies to the test jar, so that I can call a class in the test jar, and not need any other jar on the classpath.

Comment: The [maven-assembly-plugin](http://maven.apache.org/plugins/maven-assembly-plugin/) should provide a way to achieve what you want.

Comment: I'm trying with the assembly-plugin, but it doesn't let me have 2 assemblies, one without the tests, and one with the tests. I'm very new at Maven, and I find it very confusing.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In a similar situation I ended up moving my test code to a separate jar and made it depend on the original one. You can use an aggregator project to ensure that tests are run when you build the main jar.

Comment: The actual situation is that I need to pass the jar to Hadoop so that unit tests that can only run in Hadoop are run with hadoop jar <myjar> myMainClass. It's currently not finding in the jar classes that are exercised by the unit tests...

Answer (score 43):

I had a similar problem with integration tests I need to run on Hadoop. Our integration tests are located in the `test` folder of a separate integration test module, so what is required is a `test-jar-with-dependencies` to make our life easier.

I'm using the [assembly plugin](http://maven.apache.org/plugins/maven-assembly-plugin/) as mentioned by Michael-O. My assembly descriptor is located in `src/main/assembly/test-jar-with-dependencies.xml` and is a modification of the standard [`jar-with-dependencies`](http://maven.apache.org/plugins/maven-assembly-plugin/descriptor-refs.html#jar-with-dependencies) descriptor that's part of the plugin:

```
<assembly xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/plugins/maven-assembly-plugin/assembly/1.1.0"
      xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
      xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/plugins/maven-assembly-plugin/assembly/1.1.0 http://maven.apache.org/xsd/assembly-1.1.0.xsd">
    <id>test-jar-with-dependencies</id>
    <formats>
        <format>jar</format>
    </formats>
    <includeBaseDirectory>false</includeBaseDirectory>
    <dependencySets>
        <dependencySet>
            <outputDirectory>/</outputDirectory>
            <useProjectArtifact>true</useProjectArtifact>
            <!-- we're creating the test-jar as an attachement -->
            <useProjectAttachments>true</useProjectAttachments>
            <unpack>true</unpack>
            <scope>test</scope>
        </dependencySet>
    </dependencySets>
</assembly>
```

This assembly relies on the `test-jar` being created as part of the module build. So I added the following to the module's `pom.xml`:

```
<!-- create a complete jar for testing in other environments -->
<plugin>
    <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>                    
    <artifactId>maven-jar-plugin</artifactId>
    <executions>
        <execution>
            <goals>
                <goal>test-jar</goal>
            </goals>
        </execution>
    </executions>
</plugin>
<plugin>
    <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
    <artifactId>maven-assembly-plugin</artifactId>
    <configuration>
        <descriptors>
            <descriptor>src/main/assembly/test-jar-with-dependencies.xml</descriptor>
        </descriptors>
    </configuration>
    <executions>
        <execution>
            <phase>package</phase>
            <goals>
                <goal>single</goal>
            </goals>
        </execution>
    </executions>
</plugin>
```

Comment: This should be the correct answer. In addition, you can use this to build a main jar assembly by adding the following below the <descriptors> tag: <descriptorRefs><descriptorRef>jar-with-dependencies</descriptorRef></descriptorRefs>. Then the assembly plugin will build both.

Answer (score 2):

You can do this: Create a jar assembly with the [assembly plugin](http://maven.apache.org/plugins/maven-assembly-plugin/features.html), have the dependencies unpacked, pack a new test jar and attach it to the reactor. You're done.

The descriptor for the packaging could look like [this](http://maven.apache.org/plugins/maven-assembly-plugin/descriptor-refs.html#jar-with-dependencies).

Comment: That didn't quite work. The jar has about the same size as before, and I still can't execute its main class, with an exception NoClassDefFoundError. I looked in the tar, and indeed it does not contain the class in question. Any idea?

Comment: I have to learn what are "packing" and "reactors". I started working Maven very, very recently :-) Thanks for your help.

Answer (score 0):

```
    <dependency>
        <groupId>me.wener.xxx</groupId>
        <artifactId>xxx-core</artifactId>
        <version>${xxx.version}</version>
        <type>test-jar</type>
        <!-- <scope>test</scope> -->
    </dependency>
```

I use this to include the test jar.the important line is `<type>test-jar</type>`.I am not sure this is what you need.

3 years ago, but may help others.At least, it helped me. :-)

Comment: The question is not about how to use a test jar, it's about how to create one

Answer (score 0):

to include a test-jar dependency in your assembly specify the include filter of the assembly debendencySet as bellow:

```
...
<dependencySet>
    <outputDirectory>/</outputDirectory>
    <includes>
        <include>*:jar:*</include>
        <include>*:test-jar:*</include>
    </includes>
</dependencySet>
...
```

Answer (score 0):

The following worked for Maven 3

POM.XML

```
<plugin>
    <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
    <artifactId>maven-jar-plugin</artifactId>
    <version>2.6</version>
    <executions>
        <execution>
            <goals>
                <goal>test-jar</goal>
            </goals>
            <phase>test-compile</phase>
        </execution>
    </executions>
</plugin>
```

ASSEMBLY FILE

```
<dependencySet>
    <outputDirectory>demo/test-lib</outputDirectory>
    <includes>
        <!--test only dependencies (like netty)-->     
        <include>io.netty:netty-all</include>
        <!-- the actual test jar-->
        <include>${project.groupId}:${project.artifactId}:test-jar</include>
    </includes>
    <useProjectAttachments>true</useProjectAttachments>
    <scope>test</scope>
</dependencySet>
```