# Could not resolve SpecInfo from Sputnik Runner

Tags: java, groovy, integration-testing, spock, jboss-arquillian

I am trying to run Arquillian Tests using spock arquillian container

```
<dependency>
    <groupId>org.jboss.arquillian.spock</groupId>
    <artifactId>arquillian-spock-container</artifactId>
    <version>1.0.0.Beta3</version>
    <scope>test</scope>
</dependency>

<dependency>
    <groupId>org.codehaus.groovy</groupId>
    <artifactId>groovy-all</artifactId>
    <version>2.4.3</version>
    <scope>test</scope>
</dependency>

<dependency>
    <groupId>org.spockframework</groupId>
    <artifactId>spock-core</artifactId>
    <version>0.7-groovy-2.0</version>
    <scope>test</scope>
</dependency>
```

and I am getting the following error:

> Could not resolve SpecInfo from Sputnik Runner

What can cause this problem?

Comment: Have you added appropriate `repositories` section?

Comment: I think I have everything, but it doesn't work with Beta3 version. :/

Comment: You maven as far as I see? Or gradle maybe?

Comment: Gradle resolves this configuration correctly. Maybe this is a cache problem.  As in this gist: https://gist.github.com/Opalo/82594ec0d65b6a93e861

Comment: Do You have a spock dependency defined? `SpecInfo` comes from spock itself.

Comment: <dependency>
        <groupId>org.codehaus.groovy</groupId>
        <artifactId>groovy-all</artifactId>
        <version>2.4.3</version>
        <scope>test</scope>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.spockframework</groupId>
        <artifactId>spock-core</artifactId>
        <version>0.7-groovy-2.0</version>
        <scope>test</scope>
    </dependency>

Comment: Yes I think there is no compatibility between spock framework and arquillian container. When I tried to upgrade spock it doesnt work either. I am getting no such method because api changed.

Comment: Looks weird, even example from their github doesn't work.

Comment: Yes it seems I have to switch to plain Java in this case :/

Comment: Isn't it the problem you have: https://github.com/arquillian/arquillian-testrunner-spock/issues/18 ?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/81128/discussion-between-lukasz-rzeszotarski-and-opal).

Answer (score 0):

You can always build a test jar (with dependencies preferrably):

- using maven assembly plugin (see [maven assembly docs](http://maven.apache.org/plugins/maven-assembly-plugin/descriptor-refs.html#jar-with-dependencies), also [How can I make the test jar include dependencies in Maven?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7000812/how-can-i-make-the-test-jar-include-dependencies-in-maven)),
- maven-jar-plugin with test-jar goal (but then you will have to add all dependencies manually, see [maven jar plugin docs](https://maven.apache.org/plugins/maven-jar-plugin/examples/create-test-jar.html))
- or create a fat jar with any other method you like (shade, onejar-maven-plugin, etc).

After that just run your tests like this:

`java -cp xxx-test-with-dependencies.jar org.junit.runner.JUnitCore full.pkg.of.testSpec`

It works because Sputnik is a JUnit test runner, so you need to start from there.

Add any options you like, -Xms, -Danything that is needed (for example Geb needs reporting dir to be set).
Add additional classpath elements (-cp) it your jar does not contain all dependencies.