# Package JAR from LeanFT project

Tags: java, intellij-idea, jar, testng, leanft

I have a `LeanFT` testsuite with `TestNG` framework in `IntelliJ IDEA`. I generate jar file with `mvn install` command. I get error message when I try to execute it:

> Error: Could not find or load main class test.LeanFTest

`LeanFTest` class is present in test named package and contains following lines:

```
public class LeanFTest {
    public static void main(String[] args) throws IOException, SAXException, ParserConfigurationException {
        TestNG testNG = new TestNG();
        testNG.setTestSuites(Arrays.asList("testng.xml"));
        testNG.setPreserveOrder(true);
        testNG.run();
}
```

`testng.xml` file:

```
<suite name="MyTestSuite" verbose="2" parallel="methods" thread-count="1">

    <listeners>
        <listener class-name="utils.TestNGListener"></listener>
    </listeners>

    <test name="Regression" parallel="false" >
        <classes>
            <class name="test.RegressionTest" />
        </classes>
    </test>

</suite>
```

I use following plugins in `pom.xml`:

```
<plugin>
    <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
    <artifactId>maven-dependency-plugin</artifactId>
    <version>3.0.1</version>
    <executions>
        <execution>
            <id>copy-dependencies</id>
            <phase>package</phase>
            <goals>
                <goal>copy-dependencies</goal>
            </goals>
            <configuration>
                <outputDirectory>${project.build.directory}/lib</outputDirectory>
                <overWriteIfNewer>true</overWriteIfNewer>
                <overWriteReleases>false</overWriteReleases>
                <overWriteSnapshots>true</overWriteSnapshots>
            </configuration>
        </execution>
    </executions>
</plugin>
<plugin>
    <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
    <artifactId>maven-jar-plugin</artifactId>
    <version>3.0.2</version>
    <configuration>
        <archive>
            <manifest>
                <addClasspath>true</addClasspath>
                <classpathPrefix>lib/</classpathPrefix>
                <mainClass>test.LeanFTest</mainClass>
            </manifest>
        </archive>
        <excludes>
            <exclude>log4j2.xml</exclude>
        </excludes>
    </configuration>
</plugin>
<plugin>
    <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
    <artifactId>maven-assembly-plugin</artifactId>
    <version>3.0.0</version>
    <executions>
        <execution>
            <id>make-assembly</id>
            <phase>package</phase>
            <goals>
                <goal>single</goal>
            </goals>
        </execution>
    </executions>
    <configuration>
        <finalName>${project.artifactId}-${project.version}</finalName>
        <appendAssemblyId>false</appendAssemblyId>
        <descriptors>
            <descriptor>src/main/assembly/leanft-assembly.xml</descriptor>
        </descriptors>
    </configuration>
</plugin>
```

`leanft-assembly.xml` file:

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<assembly xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/plugins/maven-assembly-plugin/assembly/1.1.2"
          xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
          xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/plugins/maven-assembly-plugin/assembly/1.1.2 http://maven.apache.org/xsd/assembly-1.1.2.xsd">

    <id>fat-tests</id>
    <formats>
        <format>jar</format>
    </formats>
    <includeBaseDirectory>false</includeBaseDirectory>
    <dependencySets>
        <dependencySet>
            <outputDirectory>/</outputDirectory>
            <useProjectArtifact>true</useProjectArtifact>
            <unpack>true</unpack>
            <scope>test</scope>
        </dependencySet>
    </dependencySets>
    <fileSets>
        <fileSet>
            <directory>${project.build.directory}/test-classes</directory>
            <outputDirectory>/</outputDirectory>
            <includes>
                <include>*.class</include>
            </includes>
            <useDefaultExcludes>true</useDefaultExcludes>
        </fileSet>
    </fileSets>
</assembly>
```

**UPDATE:**
I checked JAR file and found, that it contains files from `/src/main/` project folder, but doesn't contains `/src/test/` folder, where test classes are located.

**UPDATE 06.27.**
My project structure is the same as in this sample project: https://github.com/kohli-harshit/leanft-testng-template

Comment: Is there any RegressionTest class ? which you wants to run,

Comment: @IshitaShah : Yes, sure, it is present in test named package.

Answer (score 1):

`LeanFTest class` should must contain **`@Test` `annotation`** and **Not Java main method**. TestNG will not invoke java main method. So whichever class(RegressionTest) you wants to call, Make sure it has `@Test` annotation to call.

You can check script by executing it with `TestNG` Run without executing from .XML file.

Comment: When I execute `LeanFTest` class from `IntelliJ IDEA`, it starts execution of `RegressionTest`. So it is working properly from IDE.

Comment: You are executing it from textng.xml so testng parameter is looking for @Test annotation and not java main method. Have you got error to run using Test annotation on LEanFTest class ?

Comment: I added `@Test` annotation to `LeanFTest` class, but there aren't any changes, has same effect.

Comment: I checked JAR file and found, that it contains files from /src/main folder, but doesn't contains /src/test folder, where test classes are located.

Answer (score 1):

By default when you build a jar, the classes that reside under `src/test/java` are never included as part of your jar.

So when you try invoking TestNG via a jar, TestNG wouldn't be able to find it obviously.

Please see [this Stackoverflow answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/11787964) to learn how to build a jar that includes test classes as well.

When you work with an IDE, TestNG would have visibility to all classes under `src/main/java` and `src/test/java` which explains why things work from within the IDE.

**Update**: I have updated the answer with the reference to a proper Stack-overflow answer which solves this problem.

I am duplicating the relevant sections for your reference.

The corresponding `maven-jar-plugin` and `maven-assembly-plugin` descriptions from the pom file.

```xml
<plugin>
  <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
  <artifactId>maven-jar-plugin</artifactId>
  <executions>
    <execution>
      <goals>
        <goal>test-jar</goal>
      </goals>
    </execution>
  </executions>
</plugin>
<plugin>
  <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
  <artifactId>maven-assembly-plugin</artifactId>
  <version>3.1.0</version>
  <executions>
    <execution>
      <id>make-assembly</id>
      <phase>package</phase>
      <goals>
        <goal>single</goal>
      </goals>
    </execution>
  </executions>
  <configuration>
    <archive>
      <manifest>
        <mainClass>org.testng.TestNG</mainClass>
      </manifest>
    </archive>
    <appendAssemblyId>false</appendAssemblyId>
    <descriptors>
      <descriptor>src/test/resources/assembly.xml</descriptor>
    </descriptors>
  </configuration>
</plugin>
```

Contents of the file `src/test/resources/assembly.xml`

```xml
<assembly xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/plugins/maven-assembly-plugin/assembly/1.1.0"
  xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
  xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/plugins/maven-assembly-plugin/assembly/1.1.0 http://maven.apache.org/xsd/assembly-1.1.0.xsd">
  <id>test-jar-with-dependencies</id>
  <formats>
    <format>jar</format>
  </formats>
  <includeBaseDirectory>false</includeBaseDirectory>
  <dependencySets>
    <dependencySet>
      <outputDirectory>/</outputDirectory>
      <useProjectArtifact>true</useProjectArtifact>
      <!-- we're creating the test-jar as an attachement -->
      <useProjectAttachments>true</useProjectAttachments>
      <unpack>true</unpack>
      <scope>test</scope>
    </dependencySet>
  </dependencySets>
</assembly>
```

Now when should be able to find your test classes in the created jar when you run `mvn clean package`.
Here we are basically doing two things:

1. Using the `maven-jar-plugin` we are first creating a jar that contains the test files (You should see the jar under `target/*-tests.jar`
2. Using the `maven-assembly-plugin` we are now creating an uber jar that includes the `test-jar` also as an attachment but by including it after unpacking it.

Comment: I use `maven-assembly-plugin` 3.1.0 as it described in linked answer, but test classes are not present in jar file.

Comment: @plaidshirt - Please edit your question and show us the contents of your `src/main/assembly/leanft-assembly.xml` file as well.

Comment: I added file to question.

Comment: I added sample project too for better understanding of problem.

Comment: @plaidshirt - I have updated my answer with the required information which should solve your problem.